# Cache problems when developing masterpages

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, custom-masterpage, cache

Sharepoint 2013

I am using Sharepoint Designer 2013 when editing my masterpages. However, there are times that after saving, checking in and publishing changes, it just won't reflect on the browser. I already did hard reload, emptied the browser's cache and nothing happens. One of the things I observed is that this usually happens when I am editing the html and css files at the same time.

Also, I don't know why I cannot check-in/out from Sharepoint Designer anymore. I remember I was able to do that before just by right-clicking a file. Now what I do is I have to open a browser and go to the Site Settings/Design Manager to check-in/out changes.